# Android Implementing Google Places Error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-places-api

I am trying to implement Google Places on my Android App. I already have Google Maps working and I have enabled the Places SDK for Android API to the project but it still does not recognize any of the Places's classes.

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient;
```

The project does not recognize these imports.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Place Picker is deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be available after that date. To continue using the Place Picker through the deprecation period, do NOT disable the Places SDK for Android in your Google Cloud Platform project, as doing so will also disable the Place Picker.

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#compat

Answer (score 0):

Maps != Places != Routes

You probably don't have the dependency yet on the build file. However, due to Google's recent Maps monetization policy, you will have to setup a billing account. Go here: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform and complete the mini wizard. It will do additional setup on your projects and will probably (I didn't go through it yet) give you the exact `implementation` sentence you need to declare.

Answer (score 0):

The `GeoDataClient` and `AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse` classes [were added in Google Play Services 11.2.0](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/googleapi-migration).

So, make sure that you're using at least version 11.2.0 of Google Play Services:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.2.0'
    //.....
}
```